# Get data with raw query laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know how to get data using `Order::with` and raw query, I want to retrun `$order` with `Where($query)`.

```php
public function getOrders()
{
    $order = Order::with([
        'menu:id,name,image_url,created_by',
        'created_user:id,name,email,avatar',
        'menu.created_user:id,name,email,avatar',
        'menu.categories'
    ])->get();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM orders WHERE (now() >= start_at OR start_at IS NULL) AND (now() <= end_at OR end_at IS NULL)';
    $currentOrder = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
    return $currentOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just write your query like that ?

```php
public function getOrders()
{
    $order = Order::with([
        'menu:id,name,image_url,created_by',
        'created_user:id,name,email,avatar',
        'menu.created_user:id,name,email,avatar',
        'menu.categories'
    ])
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNull('start_at')
                ->orWhere('start_at', '<', DB::raw('NOW()'));
        })
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereNull('end_at')
                ->orWhere('end_at', '>', DB::raw('NOW()'));
        })
        ->get();

    return $order;
}
```